# backbone find on collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

I know the method to find a model in a collection from a single attribute,

```
   var musketeers = friends.where({job: "Musketeer"});
```

but if i want contemporary find by two attribute and return a single result?
My idea is to find once a time the single attributes and after connect the two result:

```
   var name = friends.where({name: "stefano"});
   var surname = friends.where({surname: "maglione"});
```

and after connect the results.

I need because i'm coding a search function to find people based on name and surname.
But there is another problem:if user insert before name and after surname or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

[`Collection.where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) in fact accepts multiple attributes:

> **where** collection.where(attributes)
>   Return an array of all the models in a collection that match the passed attributes.
>   Useful for simple cases of [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter).

You could write your request as

```
var found = friends.where({
    name: "stefano",
    surname: "maglione"
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/kuLYE/ for a demo

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `filter` method to achieve it

```
var musketeers = friends.filter(function(friend) {
     return friend.get('job') === stefano' && friend.get('surname') === 'maglione';
});
```